# How do I extract the real/imaginary part from FFT in Aforgenet?

Tags: image-processing, fft, aforge

I am having trouble figuring out extracting the real and imaginary parts from AForgenet FFT.  I have the following

```
ComplexImage cImage = ComplexImage.FromBitmap(inputImage);
cImage.ForwardFourierTransform();
Complex[,] realImaginaryData = cImage.Data;
```

Does this mean I have manually extract real and imaginary parts from the complex structure?

Thanks. Any snippet would be great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with C#, but it seems as if `cImage.Data` returns a 2D array of `Complex` objects.

These objects each have public fields (see http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/09bb06de-f1c8-fc26-3472-78a64c4f4ac6.htm) containing the real (`Re` field) and imaginary (`Im` field) parts.

So, I'd imagine:

```
double realPart = realImaginaryData[0,0].Re;
double imagPart = realImaginaryData[0,0].Im;
```